# Sveltekit - How to access a "reactive context" (a store passed down via context) in the Script tag of Child Component?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, application-lifecycle, svelte-store

I'm initialising a Class in the onMount function of a Parent Wrapper component and want to expose it to all the children. I'm currently using a writable store that I set to the Class in the `onMount` function.

```js
let classA;
        
let classStore = writable(classA);
        
setContext('classContext', classStore);
    
onMount(async () => {
    const module = await import('library');
    const ClassInQuestion = module.default;
    
    classA = new ClassInQuestion()
    
    classStore.set(classA)
})
```

In a child component I'd try accessing the context like so:

```js
const myContext = getContext('classContext');
console.log($myContext) //expected: class
```

What I get is undefined until I re-render the component.

I replicated a simplified version of the problem in [this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sveltekit-cbfcmx). As you can see the context gets called correctly with `getContext`, but in the `<script>` tag the old value is still being logged. Calling `getContext` in `onMount` doesn't work either. I want to access the Instance of the class and ideally update it from a child component.

Answer (score 0):

In your child component, you could make `myContext` reactive so it triggers on every change

```js
const myContext = getContext('testContext');
$: if(myContext) console.log($myContext);
```

The output is:

[image]

At this point we dont know if the child is mounted and perhaps you dont want to trigger anything `before mount`. Therefore, we can add further conditions e.g. waiting for the childs mount or checking a condition of `myContext`:

```js
let mounted = false;
const myContext = getContext('testContext');

$: if(myContext && mounted && $myContext == "after mount") contextReady();

async function contextReady() {
    console.log($myContext)
}
    
onMount(() => {
    mounted = true;
});
```